# GoogleScript: How to CopyRow before Delete the same

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

## Situation:

I find this script, that delete the rows when the text in the column B change to "Closed". I want to copy the row before to delete into other sheet called historic.

## Action:

1. The script should be copy the row when the the status is "Closed" in other sheet called "Historic" in the same spreadsheeet.
2. Then when the first point is completed should be delete the rows in the activesheet.

## SCRIPT DELETE ROWS:

```
function DeleteRow(e) {
  try {
    var ss = e.source; // Just pull the spreadsheet object from the one already being passed to onEdit
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();

    // Conditions are by sheet and a single cell in a certain column
    if (s.getName() == 'ISP1' &&  // change to your own 
        e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.columnEnd == 2 &&  // only look at edits happening in col 2 which is 2
        e.range.rowStart == e.range.rowEnd ) {  // only look at single row edits which will equal a single cell
      checkCellValue(e); 
    }
  } catch (error) { Logger.log(error); }
};

function checkCellValue(e) {
  if ( e.value == 'Closed') {  // Delete if value is zero or empty
    e.source.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

## SCRIPT HISTORIC:

This script when somone update the column 5 will copy the row to other sheet called "historic".
When somone change the column 9 and select the status "Closed" the script copy the row to the historic and insert the closed date.

Now, does exist any why to do the same and improve the perfomance? I think this script is very complex and use many line.. I don't know if possible do the same better.

```
function Historic(e) { //CopyRows
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); // Function Date + Format

  // Get the row and column of the active cell.
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();

  // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn();

  // Move row based on criteria in column 5, and if row is not the header.
  if (colIndex == 5 && rowIndex != 1) {
    // Get value from column 5, in the active row.
    var status = s.getRange(rowIndex, colIndex).getValue();
    // Do nothing if criteria value is not actually changed to something else.
    if (s.getName() != 'Historic') { 
      // The target sheet is the one with the same name as the criteria value.
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Historic');
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber).copyTo(target);
      //s.deleteRow(rowIndex); // This line delete the source row
      targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 11).setValue(s.getSheetName()); //Insert in the Column 11 the SheetName where was modify that line
    }
  }
  else if (colIndex == 9 && rowIndex != 1 && e.value == 'Closed' ) {
    // Get value from column 5, in the active row.
    var status = s.getRange(rowIndex, colIndex).getValue();
    // Do nothing if criteria value is not actually changed to something else.
    if (s.getName() != 'Historic') { 
      // The target sheet is the one with the same name as the criteria value.
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Historic');
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber).copyTo(target);

      targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(),10).setValue(date); //This Line Insert Close Date when the user select option Close
      targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(),11).setValue(s.getSheetName()); //Insert in the Column 11 the SheetName where was modify that line
      e.source.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(e.range.rowStart); // This line delete the source row
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope you find a solution.....  Note: This Q&A site is not for people who want to learn how to program, there are lot of good sites for that. Maybe I am wrong, but it looks like you are learning how to program. ... Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see somone vote this question -1. I'm using the Historic the second part, this part copy and then delete the row.

If anyone have a better idea, I will appreciate your help.

Thanks So much